# JAVA - Encryption using an array

Tags: java, encryption

I have been working on an encryption for my program using a polybius square. Although I have got this working the requirement say's that when a word is encrypted, it needs to select alternate number for letters that appear more than once.

For example 'E' needs to be represented by 15 or 61 when encrypted and it has to alternate. I am struggling to find a solution and any feedback would be great.

Here is my source code currently:

```
public class Encryption {
private static char polybiusSquare[][] = { { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' }, 
                                           { 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M' },
                                           { 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S' }, 
                                           { 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y' }, 
                                           { 'Z', 'E', 'T', 'A', 'O', 'N' },
                                           { 'E', 'T', 'A', 'O', 'J', ' ' } };

public static String encryptMessage(String message) {
    String encipheredMessage = "";
    for (int x = 0; x < message.length(); x++) {
        encipheredMessage = encipheredMessage + encryptCharacter(message.charAt(x));
    }
    return encipheredMessage;
}

public static String encryptCharacter(char currentChar) {
    String returnGridRef = "";
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
            if (currentChar == polybiusSquare[x][y]) {
                returnGridRef = Integer.toString(x + 1) + Integer.toString(y + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    if (returnGridRef.equals(""))
        return "00";
    else
        return returnGridRef;
}
```

Comment: Much better quality of question and code than I've seen from new users in several days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a data structure that holds the next set of values to be used for the repeated characters; it only holds values for repeated characters. Initialize it upfront.

In 'encryptCharacter' check if the argument is one of these chars, and if so, use the value from the data structure and update it with the value to be used the next time (only that char).

Given the quality of your Q and the code, I'm expecting you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks a lot ill fiddle around with this.

Comment: I've been having a look at this but I am still struggling. I'm quite new to java still. Do you have an example of how this is done?

Comment: Here's an example of [Map data structure in Java](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-map-example/). I hope you have a good Java book or web site you're referring to or learning from. It's going to be a long and hard road if you try to learn through posting questions on SO or other forums.